# Rails: validation that spans multiple models, where to put it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a custom validation method that is exactly the same for two or more models. Where's the best place to put this validation method so that both models can access it and keep things DRY? If the validation fails, I also want to use errors.add_to_base, so wherever this method is put, I should be able to accommodate for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in your lib directory and then include it in. You can also create a parent class from which your models inherit and put it there, but that seems a bit over the top for something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create a custom validator that extends `ActiveModel::EachValidator` (if an attribute validation) or `ActiveModel::Validator` if it's a bit more complex.

```
class DomainNameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
```

That file should reside in `app/validators/contact_address_validator` to be auto-loaded by rails.  Each class that needs that validator could specify

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true, domain_name: true
```

where the key part is `domain_name: true`.  The `_validator` is not needed.  As you can see, your custom validator can be combined with other Rails built-in validators.